# What is the difference between Gamma GLM on log output and Gamma GLM with log link function?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, link-function

Here are two models (with R code to provide some context):

**Model 1**:

Take the `log` of the output variable $y$, then apply a Gamma GLM using the default identity link function:

```
glm(log(y) ~ a + b, family = gamma, data = ...)
```

**Model 2**:

Apply a Gamma GLM with log link function without logging the output variable:

```
glm(y ~ a + b, family = gamma(link = "log"), data = ...)
```

When I apply predictions on these two models, they give me slight but material differences. I have trouble understanding why the outputs are different.

Comment: Perhaps the distinction more readily becomes clear by considering the simplest possible versions of these models; namely, `log(y) ~ 1` versus `y ~ 1` (with log link).  What are the assumed distributions of $y$ in each case?

Comment: I would think that both models assume Gamma as the underlying distribution. It's just a matter of when to apply the log. However, I fail to see why that would make a difference.

Comment: When the logarithm of a variable has a Gamma distribution, the original variable does *not* have a Gamma distribution.  For a well-known example of this phenomenon, compare Normal to Lognormal variates or Uniform to Exponential variates.

Comment: It might be useful to simulate the distribution of the log of a gamma random variate and see that it's left skew rather than right skew. Note that in a GLM the link function doesn't transform the random variable.